# How would I add a blank line after a table in a Word Document in VBA automation?

Tags: vba, automation, ms-word

I have an Access application that generates a Word document through VBA automation.

- I need to write a set of small (separate) tables to a single page of a Word document.
- The only way I have found to get separate tables from VBA is to separate them with page breaks.
- After writing the first table, I tried the following:

```
    With Wrd.Selection
    
      .EndKey wdStory
      .InsertAfter vbNewLine
    
      .TgtDoc.Tables.Add ...
```

- However, this simply embeds the second table into the first.
- If I use `.InsertBreak wdPageBreak` instead of `InsertLine vbNewLine`, I get a separate table, but on a different page.

Is there a way to insert a blank line after a table?

**One solution**

I found this solution a few minutes after posting my question.

- Use the following commands:

```
.EndKey wdStory
.InsertBreak wdLineBreak
```

Comment: What's wrong with your one solution?

Comment: I  found the solution after I posted the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

You really should not be using Selection for this. For example:

```
Dim Wrd As Word.Application, TgtDoc As Document, i As Long
With Wrd
  '.Code to initialise TgtDoc
  With TgtDoc.Range
    For i = 1 To 5
      .Tables.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, NumRows:=3, NumColumns:=4
      .Characters.Last.InsertAfter vbCr
    Next
  End With
End With
```